# Resetting IE Personal Settings Improves Application Performance

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, clickonce

We have .NET application installed via ClickOnce on the client's workstation and in most implementations and in the office, this application is very fast. However, several clients are reporting a problem with the speed of the application and have found that by resetting the Personal Settings on the user's IE brower, the application will perform at rated speed... but only for a week or so. Then a reset solve the problem again. Obviously this is not a good solution as with each reset, stored logins and passwords and such are lost.

So why would resetting Personal Settings affect our .NET executable? There must be a lot more to the reset that we can determine. The software seems to be affected by some external environmental force. We're talking about going from 2 minutes to 5 seconds in wait time after the reset.

Comment: Well what does you application do?

Comment: Does resetting the personal settings disable extensions?  It might be extensions causing the issue.  How many are having the issue?  Are they in the same office?

Comment: What happens to your ClickOnce application folder when you reset Personal Settings?

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of the default settings.  Instead of hitting the reset button change them one by one and see which one gives you the performance bump.